# what's the iphone bottom right Coordinates?

Tags: iphone, coordinates, quartz-2d

start point of the line is (0,0). What's the bottom right Coordinates?

Thanks!

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dimensions of the device screen:

```
[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds
```

Your apps window:

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate] window].bounds
```

Any view controller:

```
myViewController.view.bounds
```

All of these return a CGRect. The bottom right is:

```
CGPointMake(CGRectGetMaxX(myRect), CGRectGetMaxY(myRect));
```

Answer (score 1):

CGPointMake(319.0f, 479.0f) it is.

Note: You may run into an upside-down flipped device-context depending on your way of drawing (CoreGraphics works that way)

Comment: correct, for that case it would be 319,459 @vladimir - however, the user asked for iPhone bottom right (device) and not for view bottom right.

Comment: hm, and why not just (320,460)? (319, 459) will be still inside the view, not on its border

Comment: obviously he asked for the view because he stated that the starting point is 0,0 ;-)

Comment: @Vladimir, it actually won't be (320,460). Screen width in points is 320, but the first point begins at 0 i.e. nth point begins at point (n-1). Don't worry though, there is only one kind of programming errors: intellectual failure and off by one error.

Comment: @Bartosz, yes, but with your logic for view with width 1, bottom right x coordinate will be 0 ;)

Comment: @Vladimir, you're right indeed, but should he decide to place a view and make only one point of it visible, thus effectively placing it in the bottom right corner, he would use (319,459) ;) Obviously, it's a matter of interpretation. Nonetheless I agree that technically your coordinates answer question better. I award your comment with an upvote! ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's different depending on several conditions.

1) Is it an iPhone 3 or 4?

2) Is the status bar at the top?

3) Are you using a navigation controller that is visible?

4) Are you using relative or absolute coordinates?

iPhone 3 absolutes would 319, 479

iPhone 4 absolutes would be 639,959

That's assuming no status bar.  If you have anything at the top, you would need to subtract those heights.

Comment: As CoreGraphics vector drawing works on points and not on pixels, the answer 319, 479 is the only correct one.

Comment: In that case wouldn't his origin of 0,0 be wrong? (assuming the status bar is there)